# Cannot get out of compatibility mode in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, compatibility

I cannot get out of compatibility mode in Excel 2007. I've tried resaving the document but that doesn't help. Thoughts?

Comment: When you click Start, Run, type in "excel" and press enter, does Excel still show it's in Compatibility mode?

Answer (score 2):

Compatibility mode is there automatically if you open an older Excel document.

Do not just re-save, but re-save it as an Excel 2007 document (you will know as it has the extension .xlsx).

When you re-save, it will automatically switch out of compatibility mode.

Comment: thanks.  that didn't work.  I don't have the option to save as an Excel 2007 doc.  Just and Excel Workbook and saving as that didn't help get me out of compatibility mode.

Comment: When you save as Excel workbook, select Excel workbook (*.xlsx) for Save as type.

Comment: Something else is the problem - make sure you are saving as a .xlsx and then close excel and re open that .xlsx file. If you are still having that problem, something else is the matter.

Answer (score 0):

View excel options --> Save 
(Excel options are available by selecting the drop down on the window title and selecting "more commands")

Set the "Save files in this format" to Excel workbook (*.xlsx)

If that doesn't work, go to resources and click "diagnose Microsoft office"